# align dos shell directory with emacs 'working directory'

Tags: windows, shell, emacs

In Windows Emacs I use the dos prompt a lot. (`M-x shell`)
Most of the time my emacs' working directory is up to date with the prompts' directory. For example when my prompt directory is c:\TEMP\project and i do `C-x f` it prompts to get files from c:\temp\project, which is desired behavior.

Sometimes the alignment between emacs'working directory and the shell's working gets lost especially when using the /D flag (`cd /D E:\TEMP\other-project`).
Is there a way to bring this alignment back?

I'm on emacs i386-mingw-nt6.1.7601

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `shell-resync-dirs` <kbd>RET</kbd>

or simply (by default): <kbd>M-RET</kbd>

```
Resync the buffer's idea of the current directory stack.
This command queries the shell with the command bound to
`shell-dirstack-query' (default "dirs"), reads the next
line output and parses it to form the new directory stack.
DON'T issue this command unless the buffer is at a shell prompt.
Also, note that if some other subprocess decides to do output
immediately after the query, its output will be taken as the
new directory stack -- you lose.  If this happens, just do the
command again.
```

YMMV in dos, however.

It looks to me like you'd need to `(setq shell-dirstack-query "cd")`, as the default `dirs` command doesn't exist in dos. `cd` with no argument seems like what is needed.

On my win32 box, I was seeing all my commands echoed back, which interferes with `shell-resync-dirs` attempt to read the correct directory, so you may need to refer to http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/efaq-w32/Shell-echo.html

However, all that done, it's still not reliable. I believe spaces in paths are throwing it out. If you have no spaces, you'll possibly be fine.

*Edit:* Yes, there's a less-than-ideal regexp in there trying to parse the directory:

```
;; regexp = optional whitespace, (non-whitespace), optional whitespace
(string-match "\\s *\\(\\S +\\)\\s *" dl i) ; pick off next dir
```

I'm not sure what the potential portability issues are here, but you can change that to the following for your purposes:

```
;; regexp = optional whitespace, everything up until the last non-whitespace, optional whitespace
(string-match "\\s *\\(.+\\S +\\)\\s *" dl i) ; pick off next dir
```

That code is in <kbd>M-x</kbd> `find-function` <kbd>RET</kbd> `shell-resync-dirs` <kbd>RET</kbd>

I see that there are a couple of related Emacs bug reports ([11607](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=11607) and [11608](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=11608)). You may want to follow those up.

Answer (score 2):

After alignment gets lost, `M-x cd` seems to be able to bring it back: specify the directory that is the actual working directory of the shell, and then `C-x C-f` uses it as a base.

Comment: Yeah that works, would be nice to automatically read the current working directory from the prompt and use that as an argument for `C-x C-f`. For now I'll make a macro out of this.

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar problems on windows with getting `shell-resync-dirs` to work.  It turned out that setting `comint-process-echoes` to `t` in shell-mode config solved the problem, for some reason the command to display the directory was being echoed even when that variable was false.